# EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT Error + Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, crash, windows-phone-8.1, backend, windows-dev-center

Our windows phone 8.1 application have lots of daily crashes entry into DevCenter Crash report, there is no any stack trace and not find any solution for it.

1. CRITICAL_PROCESS_EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_sihost.exe!sihost.exe_Task_disconnected_while_still_running:_server_task_currentState_=_Active,*targetState*=_Active.
2. EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_AgHost.exe!{537E5D95-DD83-4695-B09D-8ECB4F8741CC}_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_SystemKeyPressed,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState
3. RM_SICK_APPLICATION_DEADA444_TaskHost.exe!TaskHost.exe_Resources_were_not_released_in_time
4. SICK_APPLICATION_DEADA444_TaskHost.exe!TaskHost.exe_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_SystemKeyPressed,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState
5. WRONG_SYMBOLS_ARM_14393.448.armfre.rs1_release_inmarket_rim.161105-1459_TIMESTAMP_161106-002240_581E77D0_ntdll.wrong.symbols.dll!581E77D0165000

Whats reason for these crashes? Any solution for solve above crashes? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell the reason for these crashes without your app. You can contact [Dev Center support](http://aka.ms/storesupport) through your developer account so that they can review it with your specific application.

Comment: Thanks Mattew for the suggestion. we'll definitely try contacting Dev Center support.